# Google Ads API - OAuth2 - PHP Error - authorization_error - "login-customer-id" header - GetCampaigns.php / ListAccessibleCustomers.php

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-ads-api

With the "Google Ads API" - PHP Client Library.

While calling the "`GetCampaigns.php`" / "`ListAccessibleCustomers.php`" example code. I was still getting this error (below) but found a solution (check answer).

**Error** -

```
authorization_error: User doesn't have permission to access customer. 
Note: If you're accessing a client customer, 
the manager's customer id must be set in the 'login-customer-id' header. 
See https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/concepts/call-structure#cid
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fix** -

Pass the Manager account's ID (in my case test manager account) = $loginCustomerId

```
->withLoginCustomerId($loginCustomerId)
```

So in the “`GoogleAdsClientBuilder`” -

```
$googleAdsClient = (new GoogleAdsClientBuilder())
            ->fromFile()
            ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
            ->withLoginCustomerId($loginCustomerId)
            ->build();
```